# Symfony2/Doctrine DQL QueryException

Tags: doctrine, symfony, dql

So I'm attempting to do a query on a table that holds two foreign keys. This table basically sets a specific userID to be an "admin" of a specific zoneID in our application my DQL is this:

```
'SELECT z, zone FROM MLBPBeerBundle:TableZoneAdmins z JOIN z.zoneAdminsZID WHERE z.zoneAdminsPID = '.$userID .'AND zone.zoneId = z.zoneAdminsZID'
```

I am getting this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected end of string, got 'z'") in "MLBPBeerBundle:Profile:index.html.twig" at line 10.

From looking at the query the part in question "line 0, col 80 is the beginning of z.zoneAdminsPID which means at least in my interpretation of the error that it expects the string to end right after the WHERE which makes no sense

What makes this even more confusing is I have already successfully used a similar query to get a team name out of our games table which has a foreign key to the teams id:

```
'SELECT g, team1 FROM MLBPBeerBundle:TableGame g JOIN g.gameWinnertid WHERE g.gameZoneid = '.$zoneId .'AND team1.id = g.gameWinnertid'
```

Thank you for any help you can provide this has left me stumped as to me I don't really see a difference in how to two queries operate other than the fact they are grabbing different data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by not including the JOIN, Symfony is more automagical than I thought in the fact that

```
SELECT z FROM MLBPBeerBundle:TableZoneAdmins z WHERE z.zoneAdminsPID = '.$userID
```

From here the zoneAdminsZID was a proper zone Entity, now I believe this is lazily loading this entity aka not firing the query till I "derefence" the ZID but for us this works just fine